# What tools are there to inspect Flash SWF files?

Tags: appsec, penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners, flash

I am performing a penetration test against a website that uses Flash heavily.
What tools can I use to examine the SWF file for vulnerabilities?

---

From the [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security/14414#14414).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I have been using:
here http://www.swftools.org/ is a set of tools for work with SWF files, can be used for data structure analysis. Another one is a tool from HP specifically for scanning vulnerabilities in Flash: http://www.hp.com/go/swfscan (requires registration).

Tools that I have not used:
Flare: http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html - there are also links to other tools, and Swfmill http://swfmill.org/ - tool to convert SWF to XML.

Comment: Neighbor has topic about Flash/SWF decompilers: http://questions.securitytube.net/questions/1687/best-flash-swf-decompiler

Answer (score 8):

- SWFScan for any
- Nemo 440 for AS3, Flex, AIR
- Flare for AS2 (Flasm for disassmebly). These aren't as useful anymore
- There is an IDA Pro plugin for Flash
  disassembly written by some guy from
  Microsoft

Also see osflash.org and flashsec.org

Answer (score 5):

Another good tool that I have used successfully in the past is OWASP's [SWF Intruder](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aSWFIntruder).

Answer (score 4):

You can try SWF Decompiler to convert SWF to FLA for getting any information that might you wouldn't get from FLA Movies for penetration testing

http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/